# Mootools Add Class with variable

Tags: class, variables, mootools, addition

Is it possible to use this.

```
$('myElement').addClass('newClass');
```

And add to every element how get a new class a number.
Like this

```
myElement 1 = newClass_1
myElement 2 = newClass_2
myElement 3 = newClass_3
```

All myElement has the same class. (sorry wrote ID but mean Class ;) )

Best regards Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i find a shorter solution:

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(){
    $$(".submenu").each(function(item, i){
        var number = i;
        item.addClass("item" + number);
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```

Works perfekt :)

Best regards Matthias

Comment: perhaps you should clean up your questions and especially don't say 'id' when you mean 'class' and vice versa. also, you want to define if this is to statically do that on existing elements or get a method that will do it on new ones as you add.